# How to make EF6 Include() subclass navigation properties for a List of items

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am trying to select a list of Invoices and their subclassed items.
Here are the models:

```
    public class SalesContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }

        public SalesContext() : base ("DefaultConnection") {

        }
    }

    public class Invoice {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<InvoiceItem> Items { get; set; }

        public Invoice() {
            Items = new List<InvoiceItem>();
        }
    }

    public abstract class InvoiceItem {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductInvoiceItem : InvoiceItem {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the seed data:

```
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SalesContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(SalesContext context) {
            context.Products.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name,
                new Product {Name = "Bible - New Living Translation"},
                new Product {Name = "Bible - King James Version"}
            );
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Invoices.AddOrUpdate(new Invoice {
                    Items =
                        new List<InvoiceItem>() {
                            new ProductInvoiceItem {ProductId = 1},
                            new ProductInvoiceItem {ProductId = 2}
                        }
                }
                , new Invoice {
                    Items =
                        new List<InvoiceItem>() {
                            new ProductInvoiceItem {ProductId = 1}
                        }
                }
                );
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Here, I'm trying to select the data out with its associated subclass properties.

```
    public class SalesController : Controller
    {
        private SalesContext db = new SalesContext();

        // GET: Sales
        public ActionResult Index() {
            var query = db.Invoices.Include(i => i.Items);
            var query2 = query.Include(i => i.Items.OfType<ProductInvoiceItem>().Select(pi => pi.Product));
            var list = query2.ToList();
            return View(list);
        }
    }
```

In the above code sample, query2 is broken.  It throws a runtime exception.

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147024809   Message=The Include path expression must refer
>   to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for
>   reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection
>   navigation properties. Parameter name: path   ParamName=path
>   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T,TProperty](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 path)
>          at ParentChildEntityFrameworkStuff.Web.Controllers.SalesController.Index()
>   in c:\users\brandon.miller\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ParentChildEntityFrameworkStuff\ParentChildEntityFrameworkStuff.Web\Controllers\SalesController.cs:line
>   20
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Object tag)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   InnerException:

If I use query and get rid of the query2 stuff, it returns data, but of course leaves out the Product on the ProductInvoiceItems.  The ProductId field is set, so I know it is getting at least the value types for the ProductInvoiceItems.  I've tried and tried and searched and searched and have been unable to find a solution for this, arguably, common use-case.

What can I do in order to eagerly load the Product navigation property?

Comment: Doesn't look like you have a collection of ProductInvoiceItems on your Invoice (it's just InvoiceItem). Not sure what you're shooting for with the inheritance? Why not just add Product navigation to InvoiceItem?

Comment: Because Product is only available on a ProductInvoiceItem.  The ProductId is being loaded from the ProductInvoiceItem, even though it is not a part of InvoiceItem.  Since it's already loading value types from the ProductInvoiceItem, surely it should be able to load the rest of the information, right?